# How can I Update Boolean Value Using SQLAlchemy and Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a boolean value within a database using Python and SQLAlchemy. Here is my code:

```
def update_record_to_hide_or_show(e2e_id, hide_error, event_time, study_id):
    connection_string = _get_connection_string()
    db = create_engine(connection_string)
    roi_e2e_events = define_roi_e2e_events_table()
    with db.connect() as conn:
        if hide_error == "True":
            update = roi_e2e_events.update().values(hide_error=True).where(roi_e2e_events.c.e2e_id == e2e_id)\
            .where(roi_e2e_events.c.event_time == event_time)\
            .where(roi_e2e_events.c.study_id == study_id)
            print(update)
            result = conn.execute(update)
        else:
            update = roi_e2e_events.update().values(hide_error=False).where(roi_e2e_events.c.e2e_id == e2e_id) \
                .where(roi_e2e_events.c.event_time == event_time). \
                where(roi_e2e_events.c.study_id == study_id)
            result = conn.execute(update)
        return result
```

I am able to enter the first portion of the conditional without problem, there is not an execution error displayed as I attempt to submit the query to the database, I've created the Metadata in a separate function and the update query looks like this:

```sql
UPDATE roi_e2e_events SET hide_error=:hide_error WHERE roi_e2e_events.e2e_id = :e2e_id_1 AND roi_e2e_events.event_time = :event_time_1 AND roi_e2e_events.study_id = :study_id_1
```

I don't see that the boolean value is changed to "True" after running this, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of the table + schema or what the arguments for this function look like (particularly `hide_error`), it's a little hard to be sure, but it looks like therecould be an issue on the `hide_error == "True"` line, since it's checking if that `hide_error` is the **string** `"True"`, rather than the boolean `True`.

If it is in fact a boolean, we can actually get around the whole issue of checking what value it is by just using the `not` operator. Something like this:

```py
def update_record_to_hide_or_show(e2e_id, hide_error, event_time, study_id):
    connection_string = _get_connection_string()
    db = create_engine(connection_string)
    roi_e2e_events = define_roi_e2e_events_table()
    with db.connect() as conn:
        # no if statement here
        update_query = roi_e2e_events.update().values(
            hide_error=not hide_error # but notice the `not` here
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.e2e_id == e2e_id
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.event_time == event_time
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.study_id == study_id
        )

        result = conn.execute(update)
        return result
```

Also, if `hide_error` is being retrieved from the database, you can bundle it all up into a single `UPDATE` query like this

```py
from sqlalchemy import not_ # this is used to invert the value of a boolean column in a query - on the database, rather than a value we have stored locally in a variable

def update_record_to_hide_or_show(e2e_id, event_time, study_id): # notice that `hide_error` is gone
    connection_string = _get_connection_string()
    db = create_engine(connection_string)
    roi_e2e_events = define_roi_e2e_events_table()
    with db.connect() as conn:
        # still no if statement here
        update_query = roi_e2e_events.update().values(
            hide_error=not_(roi_e2e_events.c.hide_error) # here we use column, rather than its value, much like the `where` clauses
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.e2e_id == e2e_id
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.event_time == event_time
        ).where(
            roi_e2e_events.c.study_id == study_id
        )

        result = conn.execute(update)
        return result
```

where the `update_query` should look something like this:

```sql
UPDATE roi_e2e_events
SET hide_error=NOT roi_e2e_events.hide_error
WHERE roi_e2e_events.e2e_id = :e2e_id_1
AND   roi_e2e_events.event_time = :event_time_1
AND   roi_e2e_events.study_id = :study_id_1
```